# Does Hadoop log key to reducer mappings?

Tags: hadoop, splunk

I am viewing Hadoop log output in Splunk. I want to see which keys are being assigned to each reducer. Is this information logged by Hadoop? What keywords should I use in my query to find the relevant log lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: No, the reducers log nothing related with keys or values processed.

In BigData is not a good idea log that information since the number of log lines could be very, very big.

If you are running some tests with small amount of data, you can include some **System.out.println** lines in your reducer but take care to not let them when you start processing big amount of data.